The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'. (jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:51067/Api/Values/Insertogrenci 401
I got this error while creating my student adding page, why could it be?

The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

$.ajax({
    type: 'Post',
    url: "/Api/Values/Insertogrenci",
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',

    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": token
    },

    data: JSON.stringify({
        adi: namesurname,
        idno: std_number,
        cinsiyet: gender,
        mail: ogrencimail

    }),

    success: function (msg) {

        alert(msg);
     
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseJSON.error_description); ////gives error here
    }

});

I also received another error like this on the console page.

(jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2  POST http://localhost:51067/Api/Values/Insertogrenci 401 (Unauthorized))

I wanted what I wrote on the adding page to be saved in SQL.
Could it be related to web config??

I'm pretty sure type:'Post' should be type: 'POST' (and as type is an alias for method, it is preferred you use the method property on the settings object: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

And 401 means whatever you put in token isn't valid from the server point of view but we have no way of knowing because you didn't share what the token type is, how you get that token and how that token is managed on the server. As your endpoints seems to be functioning, it is unlikely to be a web.config issue.


type:'Post' needs to be type:'POST'. 2 seems like /Api/Values/Insertogrenci missing file extension. As well as make sure that http://localhost:51067/Api/Values/Insertogrenci file exists and has the correct permission.

